# ffmpeg: overlay video on top of a cropped video, map the overlay audio, cut the base video to the overlays length

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to overlay a video on top of a base video which is cropped to a shorts video format (standing phone). The overlayed video should be centered on top of the base layer. The base video's length should be reduced to the overlay's length. And I want to save only the overlay's audio.

I've tried a bunch of stuff without much success. The current state of my ffmpeg command is this:

```
ffmpeg -i overlay.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -to <insert base length?> -i base.mp4 -map 1:v:0 -map 1:a -vf "crop=ih*(9/16):ih" -crf 21 output.mp4
```

But this only gives me the cropped version of the base video. So my questions are:

1. How can I figure out the base video's length?
2. How can I actually overlay (not map) other video on top of the base video?
3. How can I map the overlay's audio? Since `-map 1:a` the base's audio and `-map 0:a` says: "Stream map '0:a' matches no streams. To ignore this, add a trailing '?' to the map."

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
ffmpeg -i BACKVIDEO -i OVERVIDEO -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=ih*(9/16):ih[v0];[1:v]scale=404:-1[v1];[v0][v1]overlay[outv]" -map [outv] -map 1:a -c:v h264_nvenc -shortest test.mp4
```

1. need to crop your back video `[0:v]crop=ih*(9/16):ih[v0]`
2. then need to scale your second video, in .y case is widht=404: `[1:v]scale=404:-1[v1]`
3. then you should overlay second to first: `[v0][v1]overlay[outv]`
4. Map your overlayed video and audiostream from second video: `-map [outv] -map 1:a`
5. You don't need to calculate duration of shortest video, you can use option `-shortest` before output

One hard moment is to get right scale for second video...

Comment: Unfortunately this still does not center the video on top of the base video. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: Okay I've found a solution for that: `[v0][v1]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2[outv]`.

Comment: Yep. All's right!